# Different layouts for Login Page (one for login and other layout for others) in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I creating an angular 2 application. In my app.component I've got this

```
<header-component><header-component>
<router-outlet></router-‌​outlet>
```

with the router:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profesionals', component: CrearEditarProfesionalsComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];
```

when I navigate to login I want to get rid of the

```
<header-component>
```

but for all other pages when the user is logged in I just want to display the layout as it is. Do I have to use ng-if with a service to archieve this? What's the best way?

Comment: ngIf with a service sounds good..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the  from you page. For your desired result to be achieved you can make all the components that should display the header-component as a child route of it.

You can achieve it like this:

```
{ path: 'dashboard', component:  HeaderComponent, children: [
  { path: '', component: HeaderComponent },
  { path: 'mypath', component: MyComponent } ]
},
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
```

This way every route that is a child of the HeaderComponent route will display the HeaderComponent and the child component.

And your login will not display the HeaderComponent.

Comment: Where should I locate the router outlet in this case? Right now it's in the app.component.ts

Comment: Got it when you use child routes you have to create another router outlet, this new outlet goes into the parent of the child, so there you have a new layout.